# How do I pull data from a column but without it repeating in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to enter a formula into a column that will pull data from another column in the spreadsheet but never repeat data. Say I'm working on Column A and Column D has the data I want. In Column D some cells repeat. I would like to enter a formula in A1 that pulls from D1, and A2 pulls from D2 but if the data is the same as A2 then it'll take the data from D3, and so on.

I have tried looking at IF and SUMIF formulas but I have no clue how to do this. I tried googling a few questions and looking at other people's questions on here but I don't find anything fitting my problem.

Please let me know if I can provide more information. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sifted through all of the formulas in google sheets and found `=UNIQUE`.

Entering `=UNIQUE(D:D)` in A1 transferred all of the data over to column A without repeating any of it.